# Getting an array from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save different arrays of information related to movies that are added to SharedPreferences when the user presses the favorite star, like a favorite movie list, then I'll use that list to sort a movie poster listview display screen.

Preferences variable:

```
preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("favorites_list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Here is where I add the movie (or remove) to the list when the user presses the favorite button:

```
ib = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!favoriteState) {
                ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starpressed);
                favoriteState = true;
                SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
                preferencesEditor.putStringSet(movieInfo[1], new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(movieInfo)));
                preferencesEditor.commit();
            }else{
                ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
                favoriteState = false;
                SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
                preferencesEditor.remove(movieInfo[1]);
                preferencesEditor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is where I want to get the array from SharedPreferences, but I want to get everything there not only some array based on the keyValue that I set.
Here is where I want to fetch all data in the favorites_list inside SharedPreferences:

```
private void updateMovies() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String preference = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sortby_key), getString(R.string.pref_sortby_default));
    if(preference.toLowerCase().equals("favorites")){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("favorites_list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }else{
        new FetchMoviesTask().execute(baseUrl+preference.toLowerCase()+apiKey, "i");
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I inserted them correctly, and is there a way to check on androidStudio?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can get a map of all keyValues in the preferences using `preferences.getAll()` which you then can iterate over by getting the entry set using `.entrySet()` however you wont know the data type for the value. But you control that so as long as you know that you only put in String sets you could cast to that.